# $\binom{54}{5}+\binom{49}{5}+\binom{44}{5}+\cdots+\binom{9}{5}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to calculate the sum
$$\binom{54}{5}+\binom{49}{5}+\binom{44}{5}+\cdots+\binom{9}{5}$$

---

I wrote this as $$\sum_{r=2}^{11}\binom {5r-1}{5}$$
$$=\frac{1}{120}\sum_{r=2}^{11}(5r-1)(5r-2)(5r-3)(5r-4)(5r-5)$$
I'm stuck after this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a nice combinatorial interpretation exists?  The generic sum of $\sum\limits_{k=2}^n \binom{5k-1}{5}$ does simplify to a degree six polynomial in $n$, but it does not look very pretty.  If this is an isolated problem, there are only finitely many terms... you can just add them and be done with it.

Comment: If you're just interested in the answer, I think it's $7184430$

Comment: @JMoravitz my friend asked me this question...i suppose that there exists one as in my opinion she wouldn't just prank me...but im not sure

Comment: If your goal is to just evaluate the sum, then I'm sure it equals some huge number since you can just calculate it manually. But if your goal is to find a nicer expression, then the only expressions I can think of is what you wrote and write it as a polynimial.

Comment: @Accelerator I am looking for  nicer expression

Answer (score 1):

For a combinatorial interpretation of the sum, consider $6$-subsets of $\{1,\dots,55\}$ such that the largest element is a multiple of $5$.  The sum conditions on the largest element $5r$; the remaining $5$ elements are then chosen from among $\{1,\dots,5r-1\}$.

Without the "multiple of $5$" restriction, this approach yields a combinatorial proof that
$$\sum_{k=6}^{55} \binom{k-1}{5} = \binom{55}{6}.$$

Comment: This is hockeystick identity imo

Answer (score 0):

$$f:\mathbb Z \rightarrow \text{any commutative ring}$$$$\text {forward difference notation  }\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$$ $$\sum_{x=a}^b \Delta f(x)=f(b+1)-f(a)$$ $$\text {falling power notation } x^{(k)}=x(x-1)…(x-k+1)$$ $$\text {fact:  } x^{(k)}=(\Delta x^{(k+1)})/(k+1)$$ Your sum is $(1/5!)\sum_{x=9}^{54}x^{(5)}=(1/(5! \times 6))\sum_{x=9}^{54}\Delta x^{(6)}$ $$=(1/6!)(55^{(6)}-9^{(6)})$$ $$={55 \choose 6}-{9 \choose 6}$$

Comment: This yields $28989591$, which is not the same value as the OP's sum ($7184430$).

Comment: Yeah...both expressions are not same